# How to implement Viewerfilter for a ComboViewer? I need the comboViewer to only display the elements starting with the text I have entered

Tags: java, jface

I have done the following comboViewer with its corresponding filter function but I'm unable to figure out the addListener() part and where exactly to place the refresh as I need the dropdown to refresh as I enter the search text in the ComboViewer.

```
ComboViewer comboViewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
comboViewer.setLabelProider(new LabelProvider(){
@Override
public String getText(final Object element){
  if(element instanceof Object){
    return Object.getName();
  }
  return "";
}
comboViewer.setInput(input);
comboViewer.setFilters(new CustomFil());
```

The ViewerFilter Function

```
public class CustomFil extends ViewerFilter {

  private String searchString;

  public void setSearchText(String str) {
   
    this.searchString = str;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean select(Viewer viewer, 
      Object parentElement, 
      Object element) {
    if (searchString == null || searchString.length() == 0) {
      return true;
    }

    if (element.getText().toLower().startsWith(searchString)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `SWT.READ_ONLY` in the style means that the combo doesn't have a text field that you can type in.

Comment: Yes,Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed it and tried adding keylistener for refreshing and sending the text to the filter but the combo refreshes after every key pressed rather than the whole search term.

Comment: Well how do you define 'the whole search term'?

Comment: Every time I enter a text in the combo,It searches for just the first character and refreshes rather than the whole term.
Suppose I enter "abc" it just lists the items starting with "a"

Comment: Note: If you just want a text field with 'auto completion' proposals look a the JFace `AutoCompleteField`